# Redirect url when using a native python app with the uber api

Tags: python, api, uber-api

So I'm a newbie to REST API's and the Uber app asks for a redirect url. Since I'm using a native python app and not something that is using a web framework like flask or django, what do I use there if I want to use it locally for testing and globally when deploying the app?
Will I have to use

```
https://localhost:7000/submit
```

like is given [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk/) or do I have to enter a website name for the redirect url?
If so then how would I proceed to do it?
I read somewhere that you can use the uber website itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect URL in your native python app can be any valid URL that needs to match URL you specified in your application in the [dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/). For more details how to authenticate and use redirect url please check our [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#api-token-authentication).

Comment: I understood that, but my question is more on the lines of, Do I need a new domain registered to use this? My app is a native python app running  on a raspberry pi.It cannot host a server or anything of that sort.

Comment: You don't need to register the new domain to be used as redirect URL. Registered redirect URIs may contain query string parameters, but must not contain anything in the fragment. Note that for native and mobile apps, you can register a URI scheme such as `myapp://`  which can then be used in the redirect URI. So `myuberapp://auth` is one example what you can use to register redirect URI to the application dashboard.